# Interpolation polynomial smaller than its function?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, interpolation

Let $q$ be a real number such that $q>1$ and $f$ be an entire function on $\mathbb C$ such that $\overline{\lim}_{r\to+\infty}\limits\frac{\ln|f|_r}{\ln^2r}<\frac{1}{2\ln q}$, where $|f|_r=\sup_{|z|\le r}\limits|f(z)|$. By a Gelfond's result, it is well known that one can expand $f$ in the following polynomials series: for all $z\in\mathbb C$, one has
$$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nP_n(z)\text{ with }P_n(z)=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(z-q^j).$$
Consider the interpolation polynomials of $f$:
$$Q_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kP_k(z).$$
My question: can we assert that for all $r\in\mathbb R^+$, one has
$$\sup_{|z|\le r}|Q_n(z)|\le\sup_{|z|\le r}|f(z)|\, ?$$
Thanks in advance for any answer or hint.

Comment: for $r$ big enough yes, but why would it be true for small values of $r$ ? if the $a_k$ can be anything, then I don't see any reason.